# Allow to populate drop down if certain value is in adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to figure out how to limit whether a drop-down can be populated. In one column I have performance grades that range from 0 to 4. In the next column there is a drop-down list. I want to be able to set it up so that if the performance grade is <=3, then the drop down is available and the user can select an item from the drop-down. However, if the performance grade = 4, then the drop-down is blank/not available. I've tried various options I've found online but none quite fit my scenario. Would really appreciate some help with this one!

Comment: Could you list the options you've try and tell us why they don't suit your purposes? This could save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a formula in *Data Validation List*. For example; if your grades starts from **B2** and your combobox items are at **G2:G4**:

1. Select the range that will be comboboxes (**C2:C4** in my sample)
2. Enter formula by paying attention to absolute and relative references. Use first cell of grades range and make it relative.

   ```
   =IF(B2<=3,$G$2:$G$4,"")
   ```
3. Click *OK* to create

[image: A screenshot]

An article about similar issue: [How to populate dropdown items](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-populate-dropdown-items/)